# Replaced the washer in an outdoor faucet...now it is too tight to turn on/off...wrong washer?

Tags: plumbing

The faucet turned on and off fine before.  It was just leaking, so I replaced the washer.  Now it is too tight to turn on and off.  But it doesn't leak.  Could the old washer have been trimmed to make it fit?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Some more information, such as the make/model of the faucet, and perhaps pictures of the new washer in place as well as the seat, would help.

Comment: I did trim the washer and it seemed to work...

Comment: Thanks for reporting back. Would you mind adding this as an answer to your question? That way future searchers will find out how you fixed it. Thanks.